# How can i write short code of wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode

This is a code in countries plugin, but I don`t know how to write this code in short form,

```
  function save_details( $post_id ) {
            global $post;

            $post_vars = shortcode_atts( array(
                'country_code'     => '',
                'country_list'     => '',
                'flags'            => '',
                'country_details'  => '',
                'country_currency' => '',
                'currency_symbol'  => '',
                'currency_html'    => '',
                'currency_code'    => '',
                'city_list'        => ''
            ), $_POST );
```

Can anybody tell me what short code I should write to get all the countries' names on one page?

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write your function like so

```
add_shortcode('save_details', function( $atts ) {
        global $post;

        $post_vars = array(
            'country_code'     => '',
            'country_list'     => '',
            'flags'            => '',
            'country_details'  => '',
            'country_currency' => '',
            'currency_symbol'  => '',
            'currency_html'    => '',
            'currency_code'    => '',
            'city_list'        => ''
        );
        extract( shortcode_atts( $post_vars, $atts ) );
        // country_code is now available like so $country_code
        // return data after your done

 });
```

and access it like so

```
//all of your attributes can be used inside the sq brackets
[save_details] and [save_details country_code = "" country_list = ""]
```

Comment: David Chase :i am gating error like this,syntax error, unexpected 'add_shortcode' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)

Comment: can you post how you are using your version

Comment: this is a plugin url::http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/countries/ ,i am using wordpress 3.5.1 ,David i want all the countries name ,if i click on uk ,then its display all the states of the country,an i click on state ,the next page shows all the cities of state,can you suggest plugins for that

Comment: i thought you were trying to make your function into a shortcode not for me to suggest plugins??